# OnKeyPress for Escape closes form by default

Tags: forms, delphi, delphi-7

I have a question: **How to have every newly created form in my application have  implemented an OnKeyPress procedure and KeyPreview set to True?**

I wish not to constantly add the procedure to the OnKeyPress event and set the KeyPreview to True manually.

Comment: Please remove the downvote.

Comment: What are the downvotes for? Comment at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I found is to **create a template of a form** and add it to the **repository**. Afterwards, set it as a "**New form**" in the **repository**.

In this case whenever you create a new form it will be that very template. All you have to do is change the name and caption.

This helped me in Delphi 7.

Answer (score 2):

Define your own form TKPForm which inherits from TForm and add a constructor which sets KeyPrview to True and have a keypress to do what you want in it.
Of course you'll have to override the keyprss if you need code unique to the new instance of TKPForm.

It's been a very long time since I did any Delphi but this shouldn't be too far off.

```
unit KPForm;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Buttons;

type
  TKPForm = class(TForm)

 private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    constructor CreateNew(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;
var
  TKPForm: TKPForm 

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
constructor KPForm.CreateNew(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Self.KeyPreview = true;
  Self.OnKeyPress = YourKeyPressEventProcedure;
end;
```

So then when ever you need a new form, you use a new KPForm.

Look at Visual Form Inheritance.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I prefer using the `OnKeyDown` event handler and it might be better to provide a public function to allow the user of `TKPForm` to set the handler? Frankly, I don't see what the big deal is to set these manually. Form properties, like `KeyPreview`, get changed rarely.

Comment: KeyDown event is less safer. As if the form has a drop down controls with event assigned then form will close before the actual control finishes his drop-down behavior (like lookup combobox for example). Also if the form has caFree set on Close and combobox has OnCloseUp event you could get an AV because the form is closed before the combobox closeup event is called!